# Select por grupo

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Bom dia pessoal, gostaria de sabe como fazer o seguinte SELECT no mysql:

Tendo a tabela à seguir, preciso selecionar as 3 ultimas compra de cada Nome:

[image: Tabela de Nomes]

Desde de já, Obrigado

Comment: `select * from table group by nome order by data asc limit 3`

Comment: Desta forma ele pega os 3 últimos valores porem 1 de cada Nome

Comment: Rone, você tem um ID único em cada registro?

Comment: Desculpa não ter informado, mas tenho sim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rone,

uma opção é essa:

```
SELECT A.* FROM COMPRAS A 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM COMPRAS B WHERE B.NOME = A.NOME AND B.DATA >= A.DATA) <= 3
ORDER BY NOME, DATA;
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Também tenho a seguinte situação:

Comment: O select seria com um limite de 20 resultados, porem se o Nome aparece mais de 3 vezes ele elimina as vezes excedentes, dando oportunidade para outro nomes aparecer nesta lista de 20. Também ordenado por data.

Comment: Se eu entedi bem, acredito que seja necessário apenas colocar o LIMIT 20 no final da consulta ordenada apenas pela data. Assim:

SELECT 
 A.* 
FROM 
 COMPRAS A 
WHERE 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM COMPRAS B WHERE B.NOME = A.NOME AND B.DATA >= A.DATA) <= 3
ORDER BY 
 DATA
LIMIT 20;

Comment: Coloquei assim: ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 20, ai ficou perfeito, Muito Obrigado Davy pela ajuda...

Comment: Isso mesmo Rone!